# How do retries work in a Datapower mpgw service using routing-url to set backside URL?

Tags: ibm-datapower

I have a datapower mpgw service that takes in JSON POST and GET HTTPs requests.  Persistent connections are enabled.  It sets the backend url using the dp routing-url variable.  How do retries work for this?  is there some specific retry setting?  does it do retries automatically up to a certain point? what if I don't want it to retry?

The backend app is taking about 1.5 minutes to return 500 when it can't connect, but I want it to return more quickly.  I have the "backside timeout" set to 30 seconds.  I'm wondering if it's because it's retrying a couple times but I can't find info on how retries are working or configured in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I'm open to more answers, but what i found [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/apar/IT08971) looks like it says that with persistent connections enabled, DP will retry after the backend timeout duration up until the duration of the persistent connection timeout.